# Implicit description of a vector subspace with a homogeneous system

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

I was given the following problem:

> Let $S = \{v_1, \ldots, v_4\} \subset \mathbb{R}^4$ where
> \begin{align*}   v_1 = (-1, 0, 1, 2), ~ v_2 = (3, 4, -2, 5), ~ v_3 =
>  (0, 4, 1, 11), v_4 = (1, 4, 0, 9) .\end{align*}
> Describe implicitly the subspace $W = \langle S\rangle$. That is, find a
> homogeneous system of equations for which the solution space is $W$.

Should it not be a *heterogeneous* system of equations and not a homogeneous one? For the span of $S$ is nothing but the linear combination of its vectors. It follows that any $\textbf{x} = (x_1, ..., x_4) \in W$ is defined by the heterogeneous system whose associated matrix is

\begin{align*}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        -1 & 3 & 0 & 1 &|& x_1 \\ 
        0 & 4 & 4 & 4 &|& x_2 \\ 
        1 & -2 & 1 & 0 &|& x_3 \\ 
        2 & 5 & 11 & 9 &|& x_4
    \end{pmatrix} 
.\end{align*}

This is equivalent to saying any$\textbf{x} \in W$ is of the form

$$
\textbf{x} = \begin{pmatrix} -\lambda_1 + 3 \lambda_2 + \lambda_4  \\ 
4\lambda_2 + 4 \lambda_3 + 4\lambda_4 \\ 
\lambda_1 -2 \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 \\ 
2\lambda_1 + 5 \lambda_2 + 11 \lambda_3 + 9\lambda_4
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_4$ are scalars.

Comment: The solution set of a heterogeneous linear system of equations is, in general, not a subspace. (An easy way to see this is that 0 is not contained in that set )

Comment: First, $v_4$ is not linearly independent from the other three basis vectors chosen. Second, google is your friend [check out this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1394117/find-a-homogeneous-system-whose-solution-space-is-spanned-by-the-given-vectors)